# Having one class using objects from another

Tags: c++, class, constructor, static

I have a class that I want to contain an object from another class `CRandomSFMT` (that I haven't written myself). This is `test.h`:

```
using namespace std;
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <iostream>    
#include <iomanip>  
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>    
#include <string.h>
#include "sfmt.h"

class Something {

    public:
    Something();

    private:
    int seed;
    CRandomSFMT rangen();
    void seed_generator(int, CRandomSFMT&);
};
```

and this is `test.cpp`:

```
#include "test.h"

Something::Something() {
    seed=1;
    seed_generator(seed, rangen);

}

void Something::seed_generator(int seed, CRandomSFMT& rangen) {
    rangen.RandomInit(seed);
}
```

When I try to compile this with `g++ -c sfmt.o -msse2 -std=c++11 -O2 test.cpp` I get

```
test.cpp: In constructor ‘Something::Something()’:
test.cpp:5:30: error: invalid use of non-static member function
   seed_generator(seed, rangen);
```

I tried to declare `seed_generator()` static but that didn't help. Here's the declaration of the class `CRandomSFMT`:

```
class CRandomSFMT {                
public:
   CRandomSFMT(int seed, int IncludeMother = 0) {
      UseMother = IncludeMother; 
      LastInterval = 0;
      RandomInit(seed);}
   void RandomInit(int seed);                   
   void RandomInitByArray(int const seeds[], int NumSeeds);
   int  IRandom  (int min, int max);            
   int  IRandomX (int min, int max);            
   double Random();                             
   uint32_t BRandom();                          
private:
   void Init2();                               
   void Generate();                            
   uint32_t MotherBits();                      
   uint32_t ix;                                 
   uint32_t LastInterval;                       
   uint32_t RLimit;                             
   uint32_t UseMother;                          
   __m128i  mask;                               
   __m128i  state[SFMT_N];                      
   uint32_t MotherState[5];                     
};
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've declared `rangen` to be a function; the error is because you try to use it like an object.

From your desription, "I want to contain an object", it should be an object not a function:

```
CRandomSFMT rangen;  // no ()
```

This will have to be initialised using its constructor:

```
Something::Something() : seed(1), rangen(seed) {}
```

Comment: Thanks! Now however I keep getting the error `test.cpp: In constructor ‘Something::Something()’:
test.cpp:3:23: error: no matching function for call to ‘CRandomSFMT::CRandomSFMT()’
  Something::Something() {` I tried putting it exactly like your last line, and also things like `rangen(seed) ` and `rangen(seed, 0)` inside `Something::Something()`, but that doesn't help.

Comment: @jorgen: The constructor, exactly as I wrote it (initialising the object in the initialiser list, using its constructor, with nothing in the constructor body) should work. Are you sure that's what you tried? It will fail, with that error, if you don't initialise it in the list like that.

Answer (score 2):

You're declaring a function, not an object:

```
CRandomSFMT rangen();
```

Since you're trying to use it as an object is should be like this:

```
CRandomSFMT rangen;
```